# three finger pinch with custom uigesture on uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a uiscroll that allows pinching, panning and single/doubletap functionality. I would like to add a three finger pinch in/out to trigger something else in my app. Pinch in and do this, pinch out and do that.

The builtin scroll pinch allows 2 fingers by default. How would I add a third? Subclass? Do I have to remove the gestures already on the scrollview?

Comment: Do you want to keep or replace the standard pinch functionality?

Comment: I want to keep reg. pinch/zoom with two, and add a third uigesture that responds only to three in or out

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom subclass gesture to handle the three pinch gesture. Act as it's delegate so you can instruct it to be active at the same time as other gestures. Require it to only start when there are 3 touches. You don't need to remove / replace the standard gestures on the scroll view.

Comment: I will try that out and get back to this to answer